# PyMongo + Scrapy = name must be an instance of basestring

Tags: python, mongodb, scrapy, pymongo

I'm trying to crawl a Spider with scrapy + MongoDB (PyMongo) and I'm receiving the error: name must be an instance of basestring.

Since my Spider is working, because it was scraping data to a json, I guess the error is in my new pipeline, here is the source code:

```
import pymongo

from scrapy import log
from scrapy.conf import settings
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem


class MongoDBPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.server = settings['localhost']
        self.port = settings['27017']
        self.db = settings['IngressoRapido']
        self.col = settings['Shows']
        connection = pymongo.Connection(self.server, self.port)
        db = connection[self.db]
        self.collection = db[self.col]

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        err_msg = ''
        for banda, local in item.items():
            if not local    :
                err_msg += 'Faltando local %s da banda %s\n' % (banda, item['banda'])
        if err_msg:
            raise DropItem(err_msg)
        self.collection.insert(dict(item))
        log.msg('Item written to MongoDB database %s/%s' % (self.db, self.col),
        level=log.DEBUG, spider=spider)
        return item
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you meant to connect to localhost port 27017, but instead you are using these values as keys to get values from settings. Did you mean this instead?

```
 def __init__(self):
    self.server = 'localhost'
    self.port = '27017'
    self.db = 'IngressoRapido'
    self.col = 'Shows'
```

Comment: Btw, now my collection is not being created, any suggestions why ?

Comment: Just a wild guess: when you run `mongo`, you are connected to the `test` DB. In you case you need to issue `use IngressoRapido` before you can see your `Shows` collection in output of `show collections`.

Comment: I did an     use Ingresso Rapido and got a     switched to db IngressoRapido but show collections return nothing...

Comment: Actually I inserted some prints to debug and, for some reason, the function process_item is not being called...

Comment: I thought it was working before you added DB. Now think about how scrapy suppose to know it should call your pipeline? "To activate an Item Pipeline component you must add its class to the ITEM_PIPELINES list...". http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.18/topics/item-pipeline.html#activating-an-item-pipeline-component

Comment: I came to this post but still didn't know what was wrong in my case. I am gonna share what worked for me in case people are in the same situation:  

This problem was triggered because of some problems with the MongoDB connection. 

Check your MongoDB URI and database name. In my case it was the Database name that was not correctly declared. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

The following code works perfectly and handles clean up resources properly. settings can be pulled up using the from_crawler method.

```
class MongoPipeline(object):
'''
    Saves the scraped item to mongodb.
'''
def __init__(self, mongo_server, mongo_port, mongo_db, mongo_collection):
    self.mongo_server = mongo_server
    self.mongo_port = mongo_port
    self.mongo_db = mongo_db
    self.mongo_collection = mongo_collection

@classmethod
def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
    return cls(
        mongo_server=crawler.settings.get('MONGODB_SERVER'),
        mongo_port=crawler.settings.get('MONGODB_PORT'),
        mongo_db=crawler.settings.get('MONGODB_DB'),
        mongo_collection=crawler.settings.get('MONGODB_COLLECTION'),
    )

def open_spider(self, spider):
    self.client = pymongo.MongoClient(self.mongo_server, self.mongo_port)
    self.db = self.client[self.mongo_db]

def close_spider(self, spider):
    self.client.close()

def process_item(self, item, spider):
    self.db[self.mongo_collection].insert(dict(item))
    return item
```

Note: please import pymongo in the piplines.py.

Kindly check the official docs for the same. http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#write-items-to-mongodb